# Stream video from android to RTSP server on router

Tags: android, rtsp, router, rtsp-client

I have developed an app which streams online video to an ip on the router using RTSP server and i also could get the SDP file of the stream.
How can I show that video on the ip ?
(When we go to the ip address , some kind of flash player would show the streaming video)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a the html page with video tag. Its as simple as this 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: thanks for the guide!
I have questions:
according to the tutorial I should give the video source to the tag 
what should I use as the source??
I have written this in a html file in my assets folder how should I set it as the ip page source??

Comment: Thanks. I have now made my html file in my assets folder.how should I set the page source my html file?